# Adding a class column to a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have the following piece of code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
library(tidyverse)

cbPalette <- c(
  "#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73",
  "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

## Generate data in data frame

per_spot = 2
data_train = do.call(bind_rows, apply(
  expand.grid(seq(1, 10), seq(1, 4, by = 0.75)), 1,
  function(c) {
    m = matrix(rep.int(c, per_spot), nrow = per_spot, byrow = TRUE) +
      matrix(rnorm(2 * per_spot, sd = 0.1), nrow = per_spot)
    colnames(m) <- c("x1", "x2")
    as_tibble(m)
  })) %>%
  mutate(class = case_when(    # Create ideal separation lines between data
    x1 > 5.5 ~ "class 0",
    x1 <= 5.5 & x2 >= 2.3 ~ "class 0",
    TRUE ~ "class 1")%>% as.factor)

## Plot the data 

ggplot(data_train, aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = class, colour = class), size = 4) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 2.3)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 5.5, y = 0.8, xend = 5.5, yend = 2.3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(TeX("x_1")) +
  scale_y_continuous(TeX("x_2"), expand = expansion(add = c(0, 0.1))) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cbPalette[-1], guide = FALSE) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(48, 49), guide = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(size = 15),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

Result:

[image]

Questions:

1. In the data generation code, I don't really understand how that function with parameter `c` works.
   We are not giving it any parameter at all. Let's say I would like
   500 random numbers in the column from a normal distribution and and
   another 500 data points in the second column, how would I change
   this code? I think it's the usage of the `do.call()` that confuses me.
2. When I use `mutate()`, how can I instead of assigning classes to
   variables based on rules,
   do it randomly? Say I want 70% of my data points to be of `"class 0"`
   and and 30 of `"class 1"`?
3. In the figure code, how should I change the color and shape of the
   figure? Right now they are simply set to `class` but I have no idea
   why they are blue and yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is uncessarily compact. You should rewrite it and add air, to something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(latex2exp)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

cbPalette <- c(
  "#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73",
  "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

## Generate data in data frame

per_spot = 2

an.array <- expand.grid(seq(1, 10), seq(1, 4, by = 0.75))

row.transformer <- function(row) {

    m1 <- matrix( rep.int(row, per_spot)       , nrow = per_spot, byrow = TRUE)
    m2 <- matrix( rnorm(2 * per_spot, sd = 0.1), nrow = per_spot)

    m <- m1 + m2

    colnames(m) <- c("x1", "x2")

    as_tibble(m)

}

multiple.tibbles <- apply( an.array, 1, row.transformer )

data_train <- bind_rows( multiple.tibbles )

data_train %<>% mutate(
                   class = case_when(    # Create ideal separation lines between data
                       x1 > 5.5 ~ "class 0",
                       x1 <= 5.5 & x2 >= 2.3 ~ "class 0",
                       TRUE ~ "class 1")
                   %>% as.factor
                )
```

1: The function with parameter c, I rewrote to a function with parameter row. It gets applied to every row of the array `an.array` above. Try it yourself. Fetch a row from that, and give it to the function. Each row gets turned into a tibble, which is a type of table. bind_rows then combine these together to form one giant table.

2: There are many ways. You should think through both these options: a) `rbinom( n=n(), size=1, p=0.3 )` which uses the binomial distribution, or `runif( n=n() ) > 0.3` which uses the uniform distribution and checks which are above and below 0.3. The function call `n()` works here because you are using it inside a *verb* such as `mutate`, but it is just the number or data points you have at hand. (or rows in your table if you like)

3: This is really well documented but not easily answered quickly here. I recomend reading up on using ggplot with colors, for example here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Colors_(ggplot2)/